# boostrap two divs side by side from ajax result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Hope someone can help.
I need to lay out two divs side by side from two ajax results with different number of results.

Here is my code:

```
$.each(data['middle'], function(q, z){
    $(".dep_boutique").append("<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-4'><h5 class='h5'>" + z.dep_middle_ret + "</h5></div><div class='col-sm-4'><a href='" + z.dep_middle_ret_url + "'> VIEW </a></div>");
});

$.each(data['middle_adv'], function(q, z){
    $(".dep_boutique").append("<div class='col-sm-4'><img src='admin/ads/small/" + z.dep_middle_ret_adv + "' class='img-fluid'></div></div>");
});
```

Note: the second $.each will only have three results, where as the first one may have many.

I need to get this layout:

```
1   2   A
3   4   B
5   6   C
7   8
9  10 ...etc.
```

What I am getting with the above code is:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
7   8
9  10 ... etc.
A   B   C
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't put all your `col-*` in one row if you want that layout. You have to recreate a nested structure: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#nesting

Comment: Thanks for your replies. However I now need to know how to construct the jquery from the ajax result to give me the desired layout. I can do it with static data, but not with dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of HTML Bootstrap structure:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
          <div class="row array_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="row array_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to recreate your success Ajax `data`:

```
var data= {
     middle:[{
            id: "1"
        },{
            id: "2"
        },{
            id: "3"
        },{
            id: "4"
        },{
            id: "5"
        },{
            id: "6"
        },{
            id: "7"
        },{
            id: "8"
        }],
    middle_adv:
        [{
            id: "a"
        },{
            id: "b"
        },{
            id: "c"
        }]
};
```

Now that we have our `data` and a HTML structure, we can do our loops using 2 variables, maybe it is more simple to understand:

```
var html_1="";

$.each(data['middle'], function(q, z){
    html_1 +="<div class='col-sm-6'>"+z.id+"</div>";
});

$(".array_1").append(html_1);

// -----------------------------------

var html_2="";

$.each(data['middle_adv'], function(q, z){
    html_2 +="<div class='col-12'>"+z.id+"</div>";
});

$(".array_2").append(html_2);
```

This is the result:

```js
/*This is an example of your data in return to your Ajax call */

 var data= {
   middle:[{
       id: "1"
   }, {
       id: "2"
   }, {
       id: "3"
   },{
       id: "4"
   },{
       id: "5"
   },{
       id: "6"
   },{
       id: "7"
   },{
       id: "8"
   }],
  middle_adv:
   [{
       id: "a"
   }, {
       id: "b"
   }, {
       id: "c"
   }]
 };

  /* Put this in your Ajax done() handler  */
  
 var html_1="";

 /* Loop the second array */
 $.each(data['middle'], function(q, z){
  html_1 +="<div class='col-6'>"+z.id+"</div>";
 });

 $(".array_1").append(html_1);

 // -----------------------------------

 var html_2="";

 /* Loop the second array */
 $.each(data['middle_adv'], function(q, z){
  html_2 +="<div class='col-12'>"+z.id+"</div>";
 });

 $(".array_2").append(html_2);
```

```css
.col-6{
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.col-12{
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="row array_1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">

      <div class="row array_2">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for a very detailed explanation! Worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

Brother put  outside the code after the class .dep_boutique and try again. hope you will get your desired result.

```
<div class='dep_boutique'>
   <div class='row'>
   <!-- ALL your append col-sm-4 divs here -->
   </div>
</div>
```